# How can I create a new line within a JTabbedPane JComponent Panel?

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane

I'm creating a short program that involves a guest and a tabbed pane. I want to program the JTabbedPane so when I click on a certain tab, the guest's information will be displayed using the JComponent makeTextPanel function. However, it seems to ignore the '\n' (new line) when it runs. Is there any way to fix this?

This is my GUI:

```
JTabbedPane overview= new JTabbedPane();
        JComponent accountinfo= makeTextPanel (guest.toString());
        overview.addTab ("Account Overview", accountinfo);
        overview.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

JFrame tabbed= new JFrame("AIR Reservation");  
        tabbed.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tabbed.add(overview);
        tabbed.setSize(500,300);
        tabbed.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tabbed.setVisible(true);
```

This is the toString method for my Customer class:

```
public String toString()
{ 
    customerstring= "Name: " + getName();
    customerstring+= "\nGender: " + getGender();
    customerstring+= "\nDate of Birth: " + getBirthDate();
    customerstring+= "\nPassport number: " +  getPassportNumber();
    customerstring+= "\nBalance: " + getMoney();
    return customerstring;

}
```

Thanks for the help!
Edit: here's the makeTextPanel method:

```
protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) 
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
    JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
    filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    panel.add(filler);
    return panel;
 }
```

Comment: JComponent.makeTextPanel() doesn't exist. Maybe you show us what this method does.

Comment: Oops, forgot to include that. I've edited my post to include the method. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your panel contains a `JLabel` that has as a text the one you pass in the `makeTextPanel` as an argument. A `JLabel` can have multiple lines if the text is in html format.

So your text should be encapsulated inside `<html></html>` and the line separator should be `<br>`.

Other option would be to use a `JTextArea` or a `JEditorPane` instead of `JLabel`. You can set them non-editable, if needed.